# Completely customize request headers using c# HttpClient

Tags: httpclient

The thing is I want to have complete control of what headers are sent out when using HttpClient. For example, I want to set (not add) my custom value for User-Agent, and I want to remove unnecessary headers like `Sec-Fetch-Mode` and `sec-ch-ua-platform`, which seem to be added automatically by HttpClient. Basically, I want to clear all request headers and add only precisely what I want. I tried using `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders`, `HttpContent.Headers`, `HttpRequestMessage.Headers`, all with no luck. There're still quite a few headers added automatically when the server gets the request.